# ExtJS 4.1 Controller inheritance with generated getters for stores and models

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I tried to create base controller and write in it:

```
Ext.define('My.Users.controller.Role', {
    extend      : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores       : [
        'Modules', 'ModulesList'
    ],
    models       : [
        'Modules', 'ModulesList'
    ]
});
```

But when I tried to use getters for them (in this base class, or in it's child classes, like My.Users.controller.Group), like getModulesStore(), or getModulesListModel(), I have an error that them are not functions. And in Firebug I can see there aren't this methods in child class and in it superclass. How can I to fix it?

The full description how to reproduce this bug:
1) Download ExtJS 4.1 GPL from Sencha

2) Unzip the archive, and go to directory extjs-4.1.0/examples/app/feed-viewer/

3) In file feed-viewer.html comment line `<script type="text/javascript" src="all-classes.js"></script>` to force dynamic loading of js files: now you can normally edit the content of project files.

4) In folder app/controller create file named Entities.js with following code:

```
Ext.define('FV.controller.Entities', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    models: ['Shared'],
    stores: ['Shared']
});
```

5) In files Articles.js and Feeds.js change extend to 'FV.controller.Entities'

6) In folders app/model and app/store create files Shared.js with content

```
Ext.define('FV.model.Shared', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
    {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    },
    {
        name: 'title',
        type: 'string'
    }
    ]
});
```

for Model and

```
Ext.define('FV.store.Shared', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'FV.model.Shared',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'test.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'item'
        }
    }
});
```

for Store.

7) Finally, for example, in init method of Article.js try to console.log(this); 
In Firebug you will not get getSharedModel() and getSharedStore() methods.

I've uploaded my sample to http://nekaka.com/d/W1_EOlnPST

Comment: Your code looks correct to me, so there may be a mismatch in the name/id of the store and model you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`models` and `stores` are config properties. If you look at the source of `Ext.app.Controller` you'll see the getters created in the constructor.

`FV.controller.Articles` inherent from your controller class but it has its own `models` and `stores` properties which will override the ones in your own base class. This is very much the same way as if your component has `height` config, it will override that of all base classes (unless the base class forces such config by overriding it in the constructor or initComponent, this is not the case with `controller` that uses simple config properties).

If you want this to work the class that inherent from your controller will have to explicitly merge the base class config with its new ones. Again, same like with components.

Alternatively (and probably a better solution), instead of defining your shared models and stores as config properties in your base class, you could merge these into the config the constructor gets. Something like this in the constructor of your base controller class:

```
Ext.merge( config, {
    models: ['Shared'],
    stores: ['Shared']
});
```

Comment: The parser eats my tag :) I've edit my post.
Yes, I even don't think about overriding my models and stores - I think it'll create getters before it will be overridden. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Getters are generated for views if you're using `refs` property.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller - check out section 'Using refs'.

For stores just use `this.getStore('Modules')`

Comment: I asked about generated getters, not about get<Entity>(entityName) methods.

Comment: @GuyFawkes generated getters are called get<Ref>, they are used to retrieve views. This answer is correct! There are no generated getters for models, they are used for dynamic loading only.

Comment: @sha For this `this.getStore('Modules')` to work, you'd have to have created it with that id, otherwise, a new global store will be created with the id of 'Modules'.

Comment: Juan, please read the documentation about generated getters for views, models and stores. Refs used for referencing as ComponentQuery.

Comment: @GuyFawkes - looks like you're right. There are should be getters for stores and models. I just never used them. And honestly don't see the point. Unlike views I don't understand what's the reason to use generated getters instead of standard get<Entity> methods.

Comment: It's more convenient for me :) If javascript framework provides some feature, why can't I to use it?

Comment: If you think it's a bug - I suggest you post it on the Sencha.com forums and ask them to fix it. Also, have you tried it with 4.0.7?